# Adobe Air AS3, disposing a window, profiler suggests library code

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4

My application creates a window with a few Groups. When the window is closed, the window and it's descendents are not collected by the GC.

The Flash Builder Profiler helped me find and remove event listeners to the point where i am unable to spot the problem, since it points to event listeners added from the library code of `Window.as`.

Specifically, comparing the Loitering Objects from before window open and after window close, and choosing the `MyWin` class (1 instance):

MyPackageName.MyWin (10 Paths)

10x the following line:

> Function [savedThis] 569222 GCRoot:Yes bytes:308

Clicking each "Function" in the Method panel i see the following 10 at the top of each "Function":

```
spark.components:Window:creationCompleteHandler()    Window.as line 2610
spark.components:Window:creationCompleteHandler()    Window.as line 2613
spark.components:Window:creationCompleteHandler()    Window.as line 2616
spark.components:Window:creationCompleteHandler()    Window.as line 2619
spark.components:Window:creationCompleteHandler()    Window.as line 2625
spark.components:Window:creationCompleteHandler()    Window.as line 2639
spark.components:Window:creationCompleteHandler()    Window.as line 2636
Spark.components.supportClasses:SkinnableComponent:attachSkin() SkinnableComponent.as line 694
Spark.components:SkinnableContainer:partAdded()      SkinnableContainter.as line 959
Spark.components:SkinnableContainer:partAdded()      SkinnableContainter.as line 957
```

All these are invoked from a MyWin.initialize() in some manner.

I have removed every event listener created by my code, and removed all transitions.
but still unable to figure the meaning of this and how can i dispose of the window.
Any help, would be greatly appreciated since I've been struggling for a few days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try to use 

    System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent(1)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent%28%29

or try to use 

    System.gc() 

in this way

   private var numCollected; uint = 0;

   private function gCollect(): void
   {
       addEventListeners(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEFGCollect);
   }

   private function onEFGCollect(event: Event): void
   {
     numCollected++;
     System.gc();
     if(numCollected > 2)
         removeEventListeners(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEFGCollect);
   }
```

there we use System.gc() two times in separate frames just because to collect object it's need to mark all of them as collected - and only after that System.gc() can collect objects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the best way is to make sure all references to the window in question are set to null. I have looked into this before and could not find any direct way to get the garbage collector to work immediately.